# Acceder a un control de un formulario desde otra clase C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

Si me ayudan por favor.
Tengo un formulario con un PictureBox y quiero moverlo desde otra clase,compila pero no hace nada.En el Form1 tengo mi PictureBox1 y desde la clase tengo lo sisguiente:

```
public void mover_derecha(object o, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 p = new Form1();
        p.Location = new Point(p.Location.X + 10, p.Location.Y);

    }
```

Como tengo acceso a un control desde otra clase ?

Comment: Quien usa a quien?? El punto de entrada de tu aplicación es ese formulario?

Comment: El principal es mi formulario,y la clase quiere hacer mover el picturebox que se encuentra en el formulario.

Answer (score 2):

Si es así como explicastes en tu comentario es simple, creas una función en tu formulario que mueva la imagen, al constructor de tu otra clase le pasas la instancia de tu formulario, y luego llamas a esa función. Ejemplo

Esta seria tu clase

```
class MiClase
{
    private Form1 form;

    public MiClase(Form1 form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public void mover_imagen(int x, int y)
    {
        form.mover_imagen(x, y);
    }
}
```

Aquí hice lo que te comenté arriba de pasar el formulario al constructor, puedes hacerlo así o simplemente pasarselo a la función mover_imagen(Form1 form, int x, int y), lo que con la primera opción si necesitas trabajar con el formulario puedes seguir haciendolo.

Esta es la llamada desde otra clase que no es ni tu Formulario principal (Form1), ni la clase MiClase, puede ser otro formulario por ejemplo

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        MiClase miclase = new MiClase(form);
        miclase.mover_imagen(12, 120);
    }
```

Cualquier duda tira pa aca.

Comment: No deseo crear otro formulario con New,deseo mover un PictureBox que se encuentra en un Formulario desde una clase controlar esos movimientos.Pero no he encontrado la forma de tener acceso.

Comment: Y la instancia de esa clase nueva donde la creas en ese formulario donde tienes la imagen?